# 'Весы' приоритета для значений

Tags: python, python-3.x, алгоритм, поиск

У меня есть голосование за некий продукт, пользователь дает оценку от **`1`** до **`5`**, для каждого продукта есть рекомендации с похожими продуктами. 
Я хочу сделать следующее: в зависимости от того, какую оценку имеет продукт, выбрать те рекомендации, которые будут наиболее важны в зависимости от оценки.

Например:

```
products = ['one', 'two', 'three']
vote_per_product = [1, 5, 5]
recommendations = {'one':['one recommended','recommended+1'], 'two':['two recommended','two recommended+1'], 'three':['three recommended','recommended+1']}
```

Продукт **`'one'`** имеет оценку **`1`**, приоритет в рекомендациях минимальный.

Продукты **`'two'`, `'three'`** по **`5`**, приоритет максимальный.

Теперь я знаю, что меня интересуют продукты: **`'two'`, `'three'`**, я буду искать рекомендации для них, а если есть что-то общее (в данном случае **`'recommended+1'`** вес приоритета **`+1`**).

Проблема в том, что:

- я не знаю заранее, какие оценки для данного продукта (эти значения средние из БД),
- не каждый продукт имеет рекомендации,
- если их нет - я смотрю рекомендации для следующего продукта, который идет по приоритету,
- если оценка для обоих одинакова, то самым важным становится общая часть.

Выбрать сразу эти два продукта я не могу, так как заранее не знаю оценки, лишь поочередно. 
Продуктов, с одинаковой оценкой может быть куда больше **`2`**-ух. 
Имея **`10`** продуктов с одинаковой оценкой, проблематичным становится найти рекомендации.

Подскажите, как я могу выставить приоритет веса/важности значений для данного продукта, на основе того, какую оценку он имеет?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
products = ['one', 'two', 'three']
vote_per_product = [1,5,5]
recommendations = {'one':['one recommended','recommended+1'],'two':['two recommended','two recommended+1'],'three':['three recommended','recommended+1']}

d = {}

for p,o in [(p,vote_per_product[i]) for i,p in enumerate(products)]:
    for k in recommendations.get(p,[]):
        if k:
            d[k] = d.get(k, 0) + o

rec = sorted(d.items(), key=lambda kv: kv[1], reverse=True)
print(rec)

[('recommended+1', 6), ('two recommended+1', 5), ('two recommended', 5), ('three recommended', 5), ('one recommended', 1)]
```

не каждый продукт имеет рекомендации

```
d = {}
recommendations = {'one':['one recommended','recommended+1'],'three':['three recommended','recommended+1']}

for p,o in [(p,vote_per_product[i]) for i,p in enumerate(products)]:
    for k in recommendations.get(p,[]):
        if k:
            d[k] = d.get(k, 0) + o


rec = sorted(d.items(), key=lambda kv: kv[1], reverse=True)
print(rec)

[('recommended+1', 6), ('three recommended', 5), ('one recommended', 1)]
```